# Rails - HTTP to HTTPS (or vice versa) redirect adding extra params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I am using Sslrequirements.rb (and modified it to suit my needs), now when a page goes to HTTP to HTTPS, it adds extra params. Question is how do I retain the correct parameters that are being passed and how do I make sure the controller and action name that is being passed does not go along with URL.

When this following block is invoked

```
redirect_to :protocol => "https://", :controller => controller_name.to_sym, :action => action_name.to_sym, :params => params
```

Signup page is being invoked with these parameters.

```
https://mydomain.com/signup?account=free&action=new&controller=users
```

How do I get rid of `&action=new` and `controller=users` from the invoked URL.

I am using Rails 3.2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found:

```
request.query_parameters
```

This fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The line that converts to_sym is was not converting the String to with a

> 'actionname'

Try removing the controller name and  so that your code will look something like this

```
redirect_to :protocol => "https://", :action => 'action_name', :params => [params:id]
```

According to rails documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html), redirects treat your second parameter as URL's status code.

Comment: :controller & :action is fine. It is the :params that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
redirect_to url_for params.merge({:protocol => 'https://'}).
  except(:controller_name, :action_name, ... )
```

Comment: the :params is causing the issue.

Comment: @ScottDeutsch Edited my answer--misunderstood what you were looking for.